# pyttsx3 не выговаривает фразы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

Уважаемые знатоки,

cтолкнулся с одной проблемкой во время учебы разработки на питоне - написал простой голосовой помощник. работает отличныо, исполняет разные команды. Под конец, дабы сделать общение интереснее, решил закинуть диалоговые фразы, шутки и т.д. Все фразы которые закинул, возвращались если правильно задать вопрос (все работает). Только на две фразы нет никакой реакции - *каково твое будущее* и *не пали контору*. Так же методом print не выводится желаемый реультат.

Рабочий код

```
        elif "кто тебя создал" in query:
            speak("меня создал сам бог.")
```

Если задать вопрос *"кто тебя создал"*, получаю вербальны и письменный ответ *"меня создал сам бог."*

НО

Нерабочий код

```
        elif "Не пали контору" in query:
            speak("а что я такого сказала?")
```

Если сказать "не пали контору" не происходит ничего, ответа нет. Если заменить "не пали контору" на любое другое значение, все работает.

А теперь внимание, вопрос - существует ли какой-нибуть зарезервированы словарь, который не будет произносить pyttsx3?

Гонг, минута пошла)

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант что он распознает вашу речь и первая буковка заглавная(то есть примерно так "Не пали контору"), а вы поставили строгое равенство, вот и не работает. Я предлагаю поднимать регистр распознанной фразы(`.upper()`) и сравнивать с надписью написанной капсом(то есть "НЕ ПАЛИ КОНТОРУ").Так же возможно не правильное написание в условии("е" и "ё" и тд).
Уточняйте в следующие разы библиотеки(тут вы не указали как речь то распознаете)
Вот накидал вариант с вашими фразами. Удачной учебы!

```
import speech_recognition as sr # не забудьте установить
 
mic = sr.Microphone(device_index = 0) #свой индекс
r = sr.Recognizer()
with mic as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio,language='ru-RU')
    print ("Вы сказали \"" + text + "\"") 

except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Не понял")
   
except sr.RequestError:
    print("Нет ответа от серверов гуугла".format(e))

if "НЕ ПАЛИ КОНТОРУ" in text.upper(): 
    print("а что я такого сказала?")

elif "КАКОВО ТВОЁ БУДУЩЕЕ" in text.upper(): 
    print("Не знаю")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ваш быстрый ответ. Попробовал ваш совет и все сработало.

`if "НЕ ПАЛИ КОНТОРУ" in query.upper(): 
    speak("а что я такого сказала?")`

Это то, что нужно было изменить.

Comment: Не за что, если мой ответ помог вам отметьте его как правильный
Нажав на галочку слева от ответа